# Perl: specify minimum version in env var?

Tags: perl

I'm looking for a shorter way to write simple one-offs like this:

```
perl -e 'use 5.016;say 4.3%3'
```

or

```
perl -e 'print 4.3%3 ."\n"'
```

I was hoping for an environment variable I could set that would be the equivalent of `use 5.016` so I could just write:

```
perl -e 'say 4.3%3'
```

Perhaps I've overlooked something in the documentation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
perl -E 'say ...';
```

This is like `-e` but turns on all features (which `say` is one of). From [perldoc/perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches):

> - -e commandline
>
>   may be used to enter one line of program. If -e is given, Perl will
>     not look for a filename in the argument list. [...]
> - -E commandline
>
>   behaves just like -e, except that it implicitly enables all optional
>     features (in the main compilation unit). See
>     [feature](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html).

---

To be honest: my answer doesn't exactly answer your original question. You asked how to use/require a *minimum Perl version*. For that the solution given in [@ThisSuitIsBlackNot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176646/thissuitisblacknot)'s comment fits better:

```
perl -M5.016 -e 'say ...'
```

This turns on all features that came with Perl 5.16 and at the same time complains if your Perl version is less than 5.16. Look [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html#FEATURE-BUNDLES) and [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html#IMPLICIT-LOADING) for a *when-came-what table*.

The `-E` solution blindly turns on all features of your current Perl's version.

---

You also asked for an environment variable. There's [indeed one](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#ENVIRONMENT):

```
export PERL5OPT='-Mstrict -Mwarnings -M5.016'
```

> Switches in this variable are treated as if they were on every Perl command line.

Be cautious when using the environment variable and sharing code: if you forget to tell your colleagues about it (because you set it months ago in your .bashrc), then some snippets might work for you but not for others.

Comment: may want to add that in a script, one would have to use `use feature 'say';` or `use 5.10;` or the like